# Netbeans property type hinting

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete, type-hinting

I know trying to do OOP in PHP is just silly, but here goes nothing:

In NetBeans, I can type these "vdoc" comments to give NetBeans' autocomplete a little push in the back

```
/* @var $parameters array */
$parameters;
```

But the same doesn't seem to work for class properties

```
class Foo {    
    /* @var $parameters array */
    private $parameters;

    public function __construct(array $parameters) {
        $this->parameters = $parameters;
    }
}
```

If I start adding methods to `Foo` that use the `$parameters` property, NetBeans' autocomplete shows that `$parameters` is of type `?`.

[image: Autocomplete]

--

Is type hinting for class properties at all possible, perhaps using a different syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. The answer was actually pretty damn obvious. (blush)

The correct syntax is the same as for any PHPDoc:

```
/**
 * @var array 
 */
private $parameters;
```

I'm surprised nobody managed to point this out in the 5 hours between me asking this question and me discovering the answer myself. Oh well.

Comment: For future reference: this is called a *docblock*, which is a different thing from a *comment*.

Answer (score 0):

It may go in front of the class declaration too, like this

```
/**
 * @property string $firstName
 * @property string $lastName
 */

class MyClassNmae
{
   ...
```